# how can i use net cat for chat client server model?

Tags: bash, networking

I am trying to write a daemon using bash. I will enter my partners IP address and the connection will start using nc partner_ip 2015, likewise on the server I will start the connection using nc -l -p 2015.
I want to print my name every time I send a message and also to print my partners name before his message.
So first I need to work out my partners username and ip address.

Comment: What's your specific question? Where do you stuck?

Comment: are you trying to duplicate the `write` command ??

Answer (score 0):

What you want is probably an unneeded complex way to set up a chat.
Also it is not very secure ( plain text connection, open listening socket in bash, that is asking for trouble).

Think about this: It is very simple to let him login on your computer via `ssh` remotely (instead of an ad-hoc netcat connection ) and use the `write` command (or write this part yourself).

If you really want to write the communication yourself, then at least use `ssh` to tunnel the communication like a poor-man's VPN (via port forwarding)

I persume that both your IP-address and your partner's IP-address are highly dynamic (otherwise you would just add his IP-address in your /etc/hosts and vice versa). You both will need something like "DynDNS" or write something like that yourself (in which case you both will need access to a fixed-IP server to periodically store your IP-address so the other can read it from this server).

With a more detailed question I could have given a more detailed answer :-)